# debug sql stored proc in VS 2008 from within asp.net code

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a SqlDataSource that calls a stored proc. When the page loads a Gridview loads that uses that SqlDataSource.

At this time I want to be able to debug the stored proc.

I DON'T want to debug the stored proc on it's own.

I want to see what values are actually being passed to the stored proc and what it is actually doing.

Comment: have you rights to recompile stored procedure?

Comment: if you have, you can create some table to log all input parameter values to this table.

Comment: Is there another way to find out what parameters are being passed to the SqlDataSource?

Comment: I do not have rights to recomplie stored procs. I have very little rights to do anything. I also cannot create tables.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You have to have any rights! :)

Comment: ya but I don't have those rights either.

Comment: I have rights to run select/update/delete/insert and I can create stored procs and functions in my own namespace. Thats it.

Comment: Test your code on your own sql server(with sa rights), not production. If it works at your one it will work on production.

Comment: Well i don't actually have my own personal sqlserver but I could create a local one. There is a development, test and production environments that we generally work in, but they are all controlled and they don't like to give anyone rights to do anything.

Comment: Use local server (express edition for example, or developement) with ALTER TRACE or sysadmin rights to use SQL Server Profiler. Don't use table and don't change your stored procedure. Profiler traces all calls to the sql server with param values

Comment: I have found other solution. I think, this is what you are looking for. See my second "ADDED:"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **Sql Server Profiler**. You can listen all requests to your sql server if you have rights.

**ADDED:**

["SQL Profiler without sysadmin rights"](http://www.kavinda.net/2007/01/17/sql-profiler-without-sysadmin-rights.html) or ["this one"](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/faq/How_to_run_SQL_Profiler_without_sysadmin_rights_p1.aspx) can help you.

Test your code on your own sql server(with sa rights), not production. If it works at your one it will work on production. Otherwise demand Trace rights to do to your job!

So, use a local server (express edition for example, or developer edition) with ALTER TRACE or sysadmin rights to use SQL Server Profiler. Don't use table and don't change your stored procedure. Profiler traces all calls to the sql server with param values. Just catch this calls!

**ADDED:**

I have found [ADO.NET Trace Logging](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3723011/ADONET-Trace-Logging.htm). I think, this is what you are looking for. On my opinion this tracer is not so good to use, but in your case, I think it can help.

Comment: From the looks of it I would have to have waaaayyyy more privliges on the database than I do. I don't have admin access to the database. Don't even have rights to recomplie my procs as dbo.

Comment: you should not recompile stored procedure, but you have to have sysadmin rights to listen.

Comment: I was not suggesting that I recomplie the proc, I was just giving an example of how little rights I have. Sorry, this wont work.

Comment: Sorry igor, I'm not going to be able to get those permissions either. Is there any way to tell from the .net side what parameters are being passes to the stored proc?

Comment: I guess the answer is create a local version of the database, get the nessisary rights, or do what i'm going to do. Create a temp table and modify your stored proc to insert the parameters into the temp table along with a timestamp.

Comment: @igor - To do that I would have to create a local version of the database. Meaning I would have to have to get a copy of the actual database load it into sqlexpress and then point my asp.net code to go against that sqlexpress database.

Comment: @kralco626 use your or common development environment to do this. it depends on your company's process. You have to have database to test your work.

Comment: unfortunatly thats not really an option. I could request a backup of the database and restore it locally, although I think I would run into a size issue and who knows how long that would take. Thanks for your help. I'll give u credit for the answer, since your did answer the questions, i just can't use the answer :(

Answer (score 0):

OK - this is not debugging exactly , but what you can do is put a break point in the ASP.NET where exactly you are about to call the Database ( command parameters is ready)

then go to immediate window and call this method

?DebugUtils.DebugStoredProc("Your stored procedure ",CommandObj);
this will return you a string which you can directly copy and execute in Query Analyser.

```
public class DebugUtils
{
    public DebugUtils()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //




    }


    public static string DebugStoredProc(string spName, SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        //string szSPComand = string.Empty;
        string szSPComandFirstPart = "EXEC "+spName + "  ";
        string szSPComandSecondPart = string.Empty;
        string szDEBug = string.Empty;

        foreach (SqlParameter sqlparam in cmd.Parameters)
        {
            if (szSPComandSecondPart.Length > 0) { szSPComandSecondPart += " , "; szDEBug += " , "; }

            szSPComandSecondPart += string.Format("{0}={1}",sqlparam.ParameterName, ReturnParamToken(sqlparam));
            szDEBug += String.Format(" {0} ", sqlparam.ParameterName);
        }

        return szSPComandFirstPart + "  " + szSPComandSecondPart;
    }

    private static string ReturnParamToken(SqlParameter param)
    {
        string sToken = string.Empty;
        SqlDbType dbtype = param.SqlDbType;


        if (           dbtype == SqlDbType.Char 
                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.VarChar 
                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.Xml
                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier     )
        {
            #region String - chars

            if (param.Value == DBNull.Value)
            {
                sToken = " null ";
            }
            else
            {
                sToken = "'" + FixQuotes(Convert.ToString(param.Value)) + "'";
            }

            #endregion

        }

        else if (
                        dbtype == SqlDbType.BigInt
                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.Decimal
                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.Float
                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.Int
                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.Money
                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.Real
                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.SmallInt
                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.SmallMoney
                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.TinyInt
                )
        {

            #region Numbers
            if (param.Value == DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        sToken = " null ";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sToken = Convert.ToString(param.Value);
                    }
            #endregion
        }

        else if (
                        dbtype == SqlDbType.DateTime
                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.DateTime2
                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.SmallDateTime
                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.Time
                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.Timestamp
               )
        {
            #region Dates
            if (param.Value == DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        sToken = " null ";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sToken = string.Format("'{0}'", Convert.ToString(param.Value));
                    }

            #endregion
        }
        else if (
                    dbtype == SqlDbType.Bit
                 )
        {

            #region BIT or BOOL

            if (param.Value == DBNull.Value)
            {
                sToken = " null ";
            }
            else
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(param.Value) == true)
                {
                    sToken = "1";
                }
                else
                {
                    sToken = Convert.ToString(param.Value);
                }

            }

            #endregion

        }
        else if (
                        dbtype == SqlDbType.Binary

                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.Date

                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset

                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.Image

                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.NChar
                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.NText
                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.NVarChar



                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.Structured
                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.Text

                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.Udt

                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.VarBinary
                    || dbtype == SqlDbType.Variant
             )
        {
             if (param.Value == DBNull.Value)
            {
                sToken = " null ";
            }
            else            
            {
                sToken = string.Format("UNKNOWN DATATYPE - NO HANDLER FOUND for @param : {0} of datatype:{1} ", param.ParameterName, Convert.ToString(dbtype.ToString()));
            }


        }

        return sToken;
    }

    private static string FixQuotes(string str)
    {
        return str.Replace("'", "''");
    }


}
```